# Approaching a map based selection

Tags: html, navigation

I have a map of several counties I need to turn into a county select menu (i.e clicking Leicestershire will select Leicestershire.

I am using a php built system that this map will need to return the appropriate value to. I am thinking this will be a get in the url, checked for valid values in the backend.

How would you approach this? A html co-ordinate map? Some sort of Javascript? Flash?

I am aware all those solutions have one drawback or another. Does anyone know a better way of doing this? Or an existing opensource project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a html map system. Dreamweaver made it easy (first time I've used the design screen seriously)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, if I read your problem correctly: I would personally use the Google Maps API for this. Plot each county onto your custom Google Map, then when you click each marker an info window could appear with "Select this County". Click the link and pass a value through the URL to your PHP script.